# Is it possible to programmatically create a Virtual MIDI device via Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, midi, web-midi

I would like to find or create a function that creates a Virtual MIDI device from Chrome.

This way I would find this Virtual MIDI Device/Port in my favorite DAW or else.

Is it possible in javascript or do I need to develop a plugin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible directly.  You would need to develop a native application that could be called from a Chrome extension which could be called from the page.  Also, virtual MIDI loopback drivers are different on every platform.

Comment: by platform, you mean OS? BTW your MindMaster looks interesting